# Error When Using Paginate in Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel-4, pagination

```
namespace ModAdmin;
use \DB;

class Card {
    private static $Table = 'm_card';

    //work fine when call like this
    public static function getAll()
    {
        return
        DB::table(static::$Table)->get();
    }

    //and get error when call like this
    public static function getAll()
    {
        return 
        DB::table(static::$Table)->paginate(10);
    }

}
```

can someone tell me what wrong with this paginate function..??
my Model was on Model/ModAdmin

Comment: namespace app\Modadmin;

Comment: Can your first `getAll` work?

Comment: Well you left out the interesting part. What does the error message say? If you just see *Whooops...*  go to your error log at `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`